# How to take the second derivative using multi variable chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am working on this question:

[image: Question]

Now I have the first part and found
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)^2$$ as required.

Yet I am stuck on the second part I know $$\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)$$ but here is where I am not sure is this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

However I think this might be wrong?

Any help?

Comment: Important: $f\ne F$.

Comment: Yeah sorry I realised after posting I had made that mistake they are almost the same though right just written in a different way? I.e. $F$ is considered just as a function of $x,y$ whereas $f$ is considered as a function of $u,v$ which depend on $x,y$?

Comment: Okay then @stity how do I do it?

Comment: Use again the chain rule.

Comment: How do I use the chain rule again? Sorry I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right) =
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} -
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Could you explain the first equality?

Comment: @Sam, apply again $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$.